# How to make multistage Docker build using Ansible?

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a following task in Ansible playbook:

```yaml
tasks:

  - name: Start container
    docker_container:
      name: ubuntu
      image: ubuntu:latest
      image: python:latest
      state: started
      command: sleep infinity
```

But when I enter into the container and execute the command:

```sh
lsb_release -a
```

I get a following response:

```sh
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Does it mean that Ansible installs only `python:latest` image and ignores Ubuntu one?

If so, how do I solve it?

Comment: Multi stage build are done to let you run some steps on the first image then access the resulting artifacts on the second one. If you do not have steps in the first image of the multistage build, the operation becomes pointless. Create yourself a Dockerfile build it, tag it and then, use that image.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε
 Thank you for your comment. It looks like Dockerfile is the only option to put multiple images into one container.

Comment: "_It look like Dockerfile is the only option to ..._", right. How to do so can be found under [Building, saving, and loading container images with Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/container-images-ansible) via [`docker_image` module – Manage docker images](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html) or [Ansible Playbook to build multiple Docker images without any Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/jtyr/2676e6fb3ea4bc6d7e62).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does it mean that Ansible installs only `python:latest` image and ignores Ubuntu one?*

Right, that's the case and the expected behavior. This is because of the precedence and the fact that the last value of key `image` wins here.

> *If so, how do I solve it?*

There is no solution that would work in your case without using Dockerfile and building a container out of it.
You can use use `loop` and [iterate over a simple list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-simple-list) like in

```yaml
- name: Start container
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    image: "{{ item }}"
    state: started
    command: sleep infinity
  loop:
    - ubuntu
    - python
```

but it would create two Docker containers, not one.

As according the documentation [`docker_container` module – manage Docker containers - Parameter `image`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_container_module.html#parameter-image) the module seems only to take one `string`.

> *Repository path and tag used to create the container. If an image is not found or pull is true, the image will be pulled from the registry. If no tag is included, `latest` will be used.*

**Similar Other Solution**

- [Multiple containers in host over Ansible](https://serverfault.com/a/1078102/448950)

---

Regarding the comment

> *It looks like Dockerfile is the only option to put multiple images into one container.*

you may have a look into [Building, saving, and loading container images with Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/container-images-ansible) and the [`docker_image` module – Manage docker images](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html).

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I edited it a bit so that it could be used as an answer. I hope that someone from the community will approve it soon.

Comment: @MijatTomić, yes, done.